# python3 package path of local file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-packaging

I have the following structure

```
/
/myPackage/
          __init__.py
          myFile.csv
          myFunc.py
/test/
     __init__.py
     func.py
```

now myfunc.py has a function that reads myFile.csv

```
def foo():
     with open('myFile.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
     ......
```

if I import foo in func.py the path "myFile.csv" is not correct any more.
How can I refer to myFile.csv from myFunc.py independent of the file that is importing myfunc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__file__) which refers the file path of the current module; combining `__file__` with [`os.path.dirname`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname), you can get the directory that containing the module.

```
import os

def foo():
     directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
     csv_path = os.path.join(directory, 'myFile.csv')
     with open(csv_path, newline='') as csvfile:
         ...
```

If you use Python 3.4+, you can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead:

```
import pathlib

def foo():
     csv_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'myFile.csv'
     with csv_path.open(newline='') as csvfile:
         ...
```

Comment: thanks a lot! The first solution worked perfectly for me